# How could I merge two list without using traditional for each

Tags: ruby

I want to merge two lists. One is  Active Record of list, the other is simple list.

Each object will get weight attribute after merge.

How could I do that in a more elegant way to do so.

```
a_list = [
    {name: "Jack", age: 19},
    {name: "Mark", age: 29},
]

weights = [ 38, 19
]

a_list.join(b_list) = [
    {name: "Jack", age: 19, weight: 38},
    {name: "Mark", age: 29, weight: 19},

]
```

## Traditional method

```
weights.each_with_index do |value, i|
  a_list[i]["weight"] = value
end
```

Comment: The first list is an Array of Hash. I don't see ActiveRecord objects in the example you posted.

Answer (score 2):

To do what your "traditional method" does:

```
weights.zip(a_list).zip{|value, h| h["weight"] = value}
```

To get what you have as `a_list.join(b_list)` in the code above it:

```
weights.zip(a_list).zip{|value, h| h[:weight] = value}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_list.map.with_index { |x, i| x.merge(weight: weights[i]) }
# => [{:name=>"Jack", :age=>19, :weight=>38}, {:name=>"Mark", :age=>29, :weight=>19}]
```